# Not able to install fluxgui on Ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: f.lux

I am trying to install flux on ubuntu 22.04 lts using these commands

> :~$ sudo apt-get install fluxgui
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package fluxgui

How to fix E: Unable to locate package fluxgui?

Comment: F.lux gui is not in the default repositories, but it installable via SNAP or by doing a git install.  One thing to remember is that it is pretty outdated now and has not been updated since 2019.  https://github.com/xflux-gui/fluxgui

Comment: @Terrance Could advice something instead flux?